# React import module error

Tags: javascript, mongodb, reactjs

Simply what im trying to do is export a function that make a mongodb query and import it into a react component so i can call it there and display the data.

this is the error i keep getting: ./node_modules/require_optional/node_modules/resolve-from/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'module' in '/Users/paul/Desktop/TempProject/Dietx/dietxweb/node_modules/require_optional/node_modules/resolve-from'

react component, Diet.js:

```
import React, {Component} from  'react';
import getItemList from '../server/api.js';
import ReactList from 'react-list';




class Diet extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state ={
      Calories : 3000,
      Items: [],
    }
  }
  componentWillMount(){

  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div className="diet-container">
        <p>lol</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Diet;
```

API, api.js:

```
const mongo = require('mongodb');



export const getItemList = ()=>{
  var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/food"

  return(
    mongo.connect(url)
    .then((db)=>{
      return db.collection('foodInfo')
    })
    .then((res)=>{
      return res.find().toArray()
    })
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

`export const getItemList = ()=>{`

to

`export default function getItemList() {`

The syntax you are using is importing the default member from the module but your module does not define a default member.

Alternatively, you could use the syntax

`import {getItemList} from ...`

Comment: its gives me new error 

unexpected token(5:15) pointing at the const keyword

Comment: Hmm looking at the syntax on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export it looks like you may not be able to export a const variable as a default. I will update the answer with the correct syntax.

Comment: now im back to the original error.

./node_modules/require_optional/node_modules/resolve-from/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'module' in '/Users/paul/Desktop/TempProject/Dietx/dietxweb/node_modules/require_optional/node_modules/resolve-from'

Comment: Make sure you have run npm install

Comment: i have.  i even installed 'module' alone. in a react project the node module folder is supposed to sit outisde of the src and public folders right, like at the root of the directory?

Comment: Um it should all be handled for you. If you are manually messing with things you may have gotten into a weird state. I suggest deleting the node_modules folder and any custom modifications you made to it and doing a fresh install.